# How do you stop a wrap fig from floating?

Tags: wrapfigure, savetrees

I am trying to stop a figure with wrapped text around it from floating:

```
\usepackage{float}         
\usepackage{wrapfig}        
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

...

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1, center]{MobileSignUp.jpg}
\caption{Mobile UI - Sign Up}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

The above does exactly what I want (places a figure in the exact corresponding spot in the code, with wrapped text around it), however when I import the 'savetrees' package then the image suddenly just starts floating, and goes right to the end of the document. Using flags like H in the 'float' package doesn't seem to make the image static either:

```
\usepackage{float}         
\usepackage{wrapfig}        
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[moderate]{savetrees}

\begin{document}

...

\begin{wrapfigure}[H]{r}{0.3\textwidth}     %%%%% H flag used %%%%%
\includegraphics[scale=0.1, center]{MobileSignUp.jpg}
\caption{Mobile UI - Sign Up}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

How can I fix the wrapped image exactly where I've placed it in the code whilst also using the savetrees package? Is there a way to specify a section in the code where savetrees doesn't try and comrpess? Thank you in advance!

Comment: the optional argument to wrapfig is thenumber of lines to cut out of the paragraph, using `H` in that argument can not possibly do anything useful.

Comment: please provide an example document that shows the problem, we can not run the code posted,  you can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for tests, but the example should be a complete small document where savetrees moves the wrapfig

Comment: Savetress messes with \everypar.  You can use `[paragraphs=normal]` to stop it (page 19 of manual), or simply install wrapfig first.

Answer (score 1):

To long for the comment ...

- If I insert your code fragment to small but complete document, compiling of it stops by error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   H
l.20 \end
         {document}
?
```

- if I omit option `[H`, I get result

[image]

- From above image follows, tha for wrab figuere can be reserved 10 lines, i,e, for the wrapfig option can be write `[10]`:

[image]

- Finally, if you like to have vertical aligned top of paragraph and top of image, you need to move image for  `1\baseline` up. In this case an MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[moderate]{savetrees}

\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-\baselineskip} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Mobile UI - Sign Up}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which compilation gives:

[image]

- You may have problems, if for `wrapfigure` is not enough space on page.  Than it will protrude bottom of text area on page and  insert missed space for it on the top of the next page. In such case may be desired that `wrapfigure` can float ...